# InvalidDataContractException in HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, wcf

`HttpResponseMessage` is used in web service method and I am getting *InvalidDataContractException*.

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetData()
{

    var fileContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                @"{
                                ""fruit"":""apple"",
                                ""taste"":""yummy""
                                }"
                );
    MemoryStream zipContent = new MemoryStream();
    ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipContent, ZipArchiveMode.Create);
    Zip_AddEntry("file1.json", fileContent, archive);
    Zip_AddEntry("file2.json", fileContent, archive); //second file (same content)

    zipContent.Position = 0;
    response.Headers.AcceptRanges.Add("bytes");
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    response.Content = new StreamContent(zipContent);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    response.Content.Headers.Add("x-filename", "GenInst_FMS.zip");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = zipContent.Length;

    return response;
}
private static void Zip_AddEntry(string fileName, byte[] fileContent, ZipArchive archive)
{
    var entry = archive.CreateEntry(fileName);
    using (var stream = entry.Open())
        stream.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);

}
```

The exception is:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 Type
>   'System.Net.Http.StreamContent' cannot be serialized. Consider marking
>   it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its
>   members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. 
>   If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the
>   CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework
>   documentation for other supported types.

Comment: You need to clarify what platform you are using. the tags say WCF but the code looks like Asp.net-Web-API. The framework is trying to serialize `HttpResponseMessage` and crashes when it reaches the `Stream`

Comment: Asp.net-Web-API.So what to be done to prevent the crash

Comment: And how is the above being called. Show it in relation to the Controller.

Comment: via ajax call and in the service ,the uri is handled here[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        HttpResponseMessage GetData();

Comment: Is WCF a requirement? Why are you mixing the two?

Comment: How we will do the same in WCF?